# Fundamentals of Physics vs Classical Mechanics book and physics undergraduate course

Tags: soft-question

There are books like Halliday Fundamental of Physics and there are books titled Classical Mechanics.

To me, these two types of books seem to cover the same thing.

Is there any difference?

(If anyone needs specific example, Halliday vs. Classical Mechanics by John R. Taylor.)

Edit: 
What would be the third year and fourth year undergraduate subject in physics?

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentals of Physics is the name of a first year subject in most science undergraduate programs, such as engineering or physics.

Classical mechanics is a second year subject in physics undergraduate program, dealing with a bit of Newtonian mechanics, D'Alembert, Lagrange and Hamilton.

Comment: Then, what would be the third year and fourth year subject in physics?

Comment: First of all, there is more than subject per year in physics, but it's very very standard the fundamental of physics, (it's a physics 101) for the first year and a more "deep" treatment at the second year on the same subject, via Lagrangian and Hamiltonian Formalism

At third year it's not written in stone but you will have quantum physics, optics or electromagnetism if you hadn't the second year..